# DiD with 2 groups

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am thinking about a DID approach. Typical DID can be written as follows:
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1D_i+\beta_2T_i+\beta_3 T_i D_i+\epsilon_i$$
$Y_i$ is an outcome, $D_i$ is a binary treatment, and $T_i$ is a time dummy. $\beta_3$ would be the estimate of the effect.

If there are two groups (e.g., the group dummy $G_i$) and want to get the difference between two groups after the treatment,

$$Y=\gamma_0+\gamma_1D_i+\gamma_2T_i+\gamma_3G_i + \gamma_4 D_i T_i + \gamma_5 D_i G_i + \gamma_6 T_iG_i +\gamma_7 T_i D_i G_i+\epsilon_i$$

Does $\gamma_7$ provide the effects? Is this approach the right way?

Comment: It is relevant to know whether treatment timing for the two groups is the same or whether you are considering a case of staggered treatment. More precision in defining dummy variables would also improve question quality/clarity. Finally, time indexation on variables are missing

Comment: By “group dummy” are you referring to *subgroups* within $T_i$ that are possibly more sensitive to the treatment?